# Audio fils playing at once when looping over array of audio files

Tags: javascript, settimeout

am working on Simon game app and for now have a test button. On clicking it, a randomly generated color is pushed to botPattern array variable and then I want to loop over the array and play audio for each array item depending on the item/color stored.

Now the problem is all the sounds are playing at once and not one after the another. So I have clicked let's say 2nd or 3rd time, all the color sounds in the array play at once. How do I solve this? I tried using settimeout but id did not had any effect. Here is a snippet :

```
        setTimeout(simonGameApp.playAudio(color), 5000);
      });
```

here is the code : https://codesandbox.io/s/00v44vrxj0

Hitting the test button calls generateColorSequence function.
All I want is for first array item to play, then the 2nd and so on so forth
Any ideas about how to solve it?

Comment: Please post the Codepen in your post as a Stack Snippet. Click the 7th icon 
 (with brackets `<>`) on the toolbar, copy and paste it into the editor. For more details see [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `simonGameApp.playAudio(color)` is called and the `return` value of the function is passed to `setTimeout()`. You need to wrap it in another function

```
setTimeout(function(){
   simonGameApp.playAudio(color)
}, 5000);
```

**ES6 Synstax**:

```
setTimeout(() => simonGameApp.playAudio(color),5000)
```